# implementing school-like division on 32bit chunks on x86

Tags: c, algorithm, x86, division, integer-arithmetic

Say i got two big numbers (defined below), and 
i want to implement division on them by falling back
to x86 avaliable arithmetic

0008768376 - 1653656387 - 0437673667 - 0123767614 - 1039873878 - 2231712290 
 / 
0038768167 - 3276287672 - 1665265628

C=A/B

Those numbers are stored as vectors of 32 bit unsigned ints.
First one, A, is 6-unsigned-int vector, B is 3-unsigned-int 
long vector [each of this field i name generalised 'digit' or 'field'
on my own]

The resulting C will be some 3-unsigned-int vector
but to count it i need to fall back to some avaliable
x86 (32 bit mode, though i could also hear about x64 
too, but this is secondary) arithmetic

Tell me how to count at least first, most significant
field of C resulting vector..

How to do that?

Comment: Just as the title suggests and those school books show. Apropos: what have you tried? (and please try to refine the wording in `B is 3-unsigned-int long vector` (how about throwing in an article?))

Comment: Have you looked at the GMP (GNU Multi-precision) library?  It has optimized asm for many platforms, as well a C implementations that might have some useful comments.  When you say "count", do mean "calculate"?  Or determine if non-zero?

Comment: got GMP sopurces but i need just to understood this simple algorithm details before

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here is unsigned long division pseudocode for any size operand from [wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Division_algorithm):

```
if D == 0 then
    error(DivisionByZeroException) end
Q := 0                 -- initialize quotient and remainder to zero
R := 0                     
for i = n-1...0 do     -- where n is number of bits in N
  R := R << 1          -- left-shift R by 1 bit
  R(0) := N(i)         -- set the least-significant bit of R equal to bit i of the numerator
  if R >= D then
    R := R - D
    Q(i) := 1
  end
end
```

This can be extended to include signed division as well (rounding the result toward zero, not negative infinity):

```
if D == 0 then
    error(DivisionByZeroException) end
Q := 0                 -- initialize quotient and remainder to zero
R := 0  
SaveN := N             -- save numerator
SaveD := D             -- save denominator
if N < 0 then N = -N   -- invert numerator if negative
if D < 0 then D = -D   -- invert denominator if negative
for i = n-1...0 do     -- where n is number of bits in N
  R := R << 1          -- left-shift R by 1 bit
  R(0) := N(i)         -- set the least-significant bit of R equal to bit i of the numerator
  if R >= D then
    R := R - D
    Q(i) := 1
  end
end
if SaveN < 0 then
    R = -R             -- numerator was negative, negative remainder
if (SaveN < 0 and SaveD >= 0) or (SaveN >= 0 and SaveD < 0) then
    Q = -Q             -- differing signs of inputs, result is negative
```

Here is a relatively simple, unoptimized, **untested** implementation in x86 ASM (NASM syntax) that should be easy to understand:

```
        ; function div_192_96
        ; parameters:
        ;                 24 bytes: numerator, high words are stored after low words
        ;                 24 bytes: denominator, high words are stored after low words (only low 12 bytes are used)
        ;                  4 bytes: address to store 12 byte remainder in (must not be NULL)
        ;                  4 bytes: address to store 12 byte quotient in (must not be NULL)
        ; return value:   none
        ; error checking: none

        GLOBAL  div_192_96
div_192_96:
        pushl   ebp             ; set up stack frame
        movl    ebp, esp
        pushl   0               ; high word of remainder
        pushl   0               ; middle word of remainder
        pushl   0               ; low word of remainder
        pushl   0               ; high word of quotient
        pushl   0               ; middle word of quotient
        pushl   0               ; low word of quotient
        movl    ecx, 96
.div_loop:
        jecxz   .div_loop_done
        decl    ecx
        ; remainder = remainder << 1
        movl    eax, [ebp-8]    ; load middle word of remainder
        shld    [ebp-4], eax, 1 ; shift high word of remainder left by 1
        movl    eax, [ebp-12]   ; load low word of remainder
        shld    [ebp-8], eax, 1 ; shift middle word of remainder left by 1
        shll    [ebp-12], 1     ; shift low word of remainder left by 1
        ; quotient = quotient << 1
        movl    eax, [ebp-20]   ; load middle word of remainder
        shld    [ebp-16], eax, 1; shift high word of remainder left by 1
        movl    eax, [ebp-24]   ; load low word of remainder
        shld    [ebp-20], eax, 1; shift middle word of remainder left by 1
        shll    [ebp-24], 1     ; shift low word of remainder left by 1
        ; remainder(0) = numerator(127)
        movl    eax, [ebp+28]   ; load high word of numerator
        shrl    eax, 31         ; get top bit in bit 0
        orl     [ebp-12], eax   ; OR into low word of remainder
        ; numerator = numerator << 1
        movl    eax, [ebp+24]   ; load 5th word of numerator
        shld    [ebp+28], eax, 1; shift 6th word of numerator left by 1
        movl    eax, [ebp+20]   ; load 4th word of numerator
        shld    [ebp+24], eax, 1; shift 5th word of numerator left by 1
        movl    eax, [ebp+16]   ; load 3rd word of numerator
        shld    [ebp+20], eax, 1; shift 4th word of numerator left by 1
        movl    eax, [ebp+12]   ; load 2nd word of numerator
        shld    [ebp+16], eax, 1; shift 3rd word of numerator left by 1
        movl    eax, [ebp+8]    ; load 1st word of numerator
        shld    [ebp+12], eax, 1; shift 2nd word of numerator left by 1
        shll    [ebp+8], 1      ; shift 1st word of numerator left by 1
        ; if (remainder >= denominator)
        movl    eax, [ebp+40]   ; compare high word of denominator
        cmpl    eax, [ebp-4]    ; with high word of remainder
        jb      .div_loop
        ja      .div_subtract
        movl    eax, [ebp+36]   ; compare middle word of denominator
        cmpl    eax, [ebp-8]    ; with middle word of remainder
        jb      .div_loop
        ja      .div_subtract
        movl    eax, [ebp+32]   ; compare low word of denominator
        cmpl    eax, [ebp-12]   ; with low word of remainder
        jb      .div_loop
.div_subtract:
        ; remainder = remainder - denominator
        movl    eax, [ebp+32]   ; load low word of denominator
        subl    [ebp-12], eax   ; and subtract from low word of remainder
        movl    eax, [ebp+36]   ; load middle word of denominator
        sbbl    [ebp-8], eax    ; and subtract from middle word of remainder (with borrow)
        movl    eax, [ebp+40]   ; load high word of denominator
        sbbl    [ebp-4], eax    ; and subtract from high word of remainder (with borrow)
        ; quotient(0) = 1
        orl     [ebp-24], 1     ; OR 1 into low word of quotient
        jmp     .div_loop
.div_loop_done:
        movl    eax, [ebp+56]   ; load remainder storage pointer
        movl    edx, [ebp-12]   ; load low word of remainder
        movl    [eax+0], edx    ; store low word of remainder
        movl    edx, [ebp-8]    ; load middle word of remainder
        movl    [eax+4], edx    ; store middle word of remainder
        movl    edx, [ebp-4]    ; load high word of remainder
        movl    [eax+8], edx    ; store high word of remainder
        movl    eax, [ebp+60]   ; load quotient storage pointer
        movl    edx, [ebp-24]   ; load low word of quotient
        movl    [eax+0], edx    ; store low word of quotient
        movl    edx, [ebp-20]   ; load middle word of quotient
        movl    [eax+4], edx    ; store middle word of quotient
        movl    edx, [ebp-16]   ; load high word of quotient
        movl    [eax+8], edx    ; store high word of quotient
        addl    esp, 24
        popl    ebp
        ret
```

Please note that this is just to give you a general idea, and has not been tested. BTW, it's probably easier to calculate the quotient of two numbers of equal size in assembly than to try to work around overflow issues (which are completely unhandled in above code).

Answer (score 1):

[GMP's docs include a section on the algorithms it uses](https://gmplib.org/manual/Division-Algorithms.html#Division-Algorithms), including division.  In GMP terminology, each of your 32b chunks are called "limbs".

64bit CPUs are very good for extended precision math, because they process twice as much at once, with about the same time per operation.  If you want to implement extended precision yourself, instead of using the LGPLed [GMP library](https://gmplib.org/), I'd recommend x86-64 asm with a fallback to C.  (Unless you want to use it as part of something that you want to ship only as legacy 32bit binaries.)

Division is the exception to this rule, though: On recent x86 designs from Intel and AMD, 128b / 64b = 64b division has worse latency and lower throughput than 64b / 32b = 32b division.  See http://agner.org/optimize/, look for `div` in the instruction tables.  `idiv` is signed division, `div` is unsigned.)  By contrast, `ADC` (add with carry) has 1-per-cycle throughput, same as 64bit `MUL` (and `IMUL`).

Actually, on Intel Sandybridge-family at least, `MUL/IMUL` 64bit * 64bit = 128bit is *faster* than `IMUL/MUL` 32bit * 32bit = 64bit.  mul 32bit is 3 uops, with a throughput of one per 2 cycles, vs. mul 64bit being 2 uops with a throughput of one per cycle.  The one-operand form of `mul` does `rdx:rax = rax * src`.  I guess there's an extra cycle needed to split/shuffle a 64bit result out of the multiplier into edx:eax, which is set up to produce two 64bit halves of a 128b result.

On AMD Bulldozer-family CPU, 32bit mul is faster than 64bit mul.  I guess they don't have full-width multiplier hardware.

(For normal usage by a compiler, `c = a*b` usually has the same width for all variables, so the upper half of the result can be discarded.  x86 has a `dest *= src`  two-operand form of `imul` (but not `mul`) which is the same speed as the fastest one-operand form.  So don't worry about using `long`s so they'll multiply faster in normal code.)

This applies whether the CPU is running 32bit or 64bit code, except that 32bit code can't do 64bit operations.

You were asking about `div`, and I got off on a tangent.  x86's `div` instruction does rdx:rax / src, outputting rax=quotient, rdx=remainder.  Or edx:eax ... for the 32bit version.

Comment: this was helpful but this is on optimisation (i will be doin eventaually a bit later).. now i would like to strightly code it in c and i dont know the simple algorithm, which unsigned divide by which unsigned to get right output unsigneds..

Comment: @user2214913: I don't know it either.  I just answered the part that I knew how to answer.  Go look at GMP's code. :P  I didn't intend this as *the* answer to your main question, but I had more to say than I could leave in a comment.

Comment: @user2214913: updated with a link to GMP's docs that describe the division algorithms it uses.